# How to remove duplicates in one column based on the value of other columns in psql

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a database which is supposed to imitate a library management system. I want to write a query that, present a table that shows the top 3 borrowed books for each publisher, also showing their corresponding rank (so the book borrowed the most times from publisher X will show rank 1). I have a query that displays the information below - title of borrowed books together with their corresponding publisher, and the amount of times each book has been borrowed. As you can see; Bloomsbury (UK) is present 7 times (one for each Harry Potter book) but I want it to only display the 3 most popular Harry Potter books in regards to amount of times borrowed. I'm very thankful for any help.

```
                  title                   |       publisher        | times
------------------------------------------+------------------------+------
 Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone | Bloomsbury (UK)        |    2
 Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows     | Bloomsbury (UK)        |    2
 Harry Potter the Goblet of Fire          | Bloomsbury (UK)        |    3
 The Fellowship of the Ring               | George Allen & Unwin   |    1
 Calculus                                 | Paerson Addison Wesley |    1
 Go Set a Watchman                        | HarperCollins          |    1
 Harry Potter the Half-Blood Prince       | Bloomsbury (UK)        |    4
 Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets  | Bloomsbury (UK)        |    3
 Harry Potter and Prisoner of Azkaban     | Bloomsbury (UK)        |    2
 Nineteen Eighty-Four                     | Secker & Warburg       |    1
 Harry Potter the Order of the Phoenix    | Bloomsbury (UK)        |    4
 To Kill a Mockingbird                    | J.B.Lippincott & Co    |    1
```

The query below will generate the view above.

```
SELECT title, publisher, COUNT(borrowed.resid) AS rank 
FROM borrowed 
  CROSS JOIN book 
  CROSS JOIN bookinfo 
WHERE borrowed.resid = book.resid 
  AND book.isbn = bookinfo.isbn 
  AND book.copynumber = borrowed.copynumber 
GROUP BY title, publisher;
```

Comment: Why use a convoluted cross join instead of a proper `JOIN ... ON ...`?

Comment: Because I'm very bad at SQL and cross join is the only type of join I understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixing the joins and adding RANK:

```
select *
from 
 (
    SELECT title, publisher, COUNT(*) AS cnt,
       -- rank the counts
       rank() over (partition by publisher order by count(*) desc) as rnk 
    FROM borrowed 
      JOIN book 
        ON borrowed.resid = book.resid 
       AND book.copynumber = borrowed.copynumber 
      JOIN bookinfo 
        ON book.isbn = bookinfo.isbn 
    GROUP BY title, publisher
 ) as dt
where rnk <= 3
```

You might want to switch to `ROW_NUMBER` (exactly 3 rows) or `DENSE_RANK` (3 highest counts) instead of `RANK` (3 rows, maybe more if row #4+ got the same count as row #3).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT title, publisher, times
FROM (
    SELECT *, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY publisher ORDER BY times DESC) AS ranking
    FROM (
        SELECT title, publisher, COUNT(resid) AS times 
        FROM borrowed 
        JOIN book USING (resid, copynumber)
        JOIN bookinfo USING (isbn)
        GROUP BY title, publisher
    ) AS counts
) AS ranks
WHERE ranking <= 3
ORDER BY publisher, times DESC
```

`counts` is the part you wrote, adjusted to utilize `USING` to combine same named columns from both sides (makes it shorter)

`ranks` is the part that ranks per publisher using `rank` function (window fuction)

finally, we take the top 3 by picking ranking equal and lower than 3.